# Jekyll multidirectory website

Tags: jekyll

I'm moving my website to Jekyll since Wordpress is way too bloated and far from easy to use for a simple blog+portfolio. I am then facing a problem which I could not solve looking at the documentation (and even the examples, since they are very very simple).

I want to have a site with a landing page at `/` (ok), a blog on the directory `/blog/` and the posts at `/blog/post-title/` (ok, I think) and a portfolio with my jobs at `/portfolio/` with jobs at `/portfolio/job-title/`, but I cannot create this last directory.

I tried creating a `_jobs` dir inside the `portfolio` dir, and then looping through it with

```
{% for job in site.jobs %}
  ...html...
{% endfor %}
```

Since the blog example uses this same syntax, but with `posts` instead of `jobs`. How should I do to access this `portfolio/_jobs` directory and loop through the files?

The tree of the Jekyll folder is as follows:

```
.
├── blog
│   ├── index.html
│   └── _posts
│       ├── 2013-02-19-hello-world.markdown
│       └── 2014-03-01-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown
├── _config.yml
├── css
│   ├── main.css
│   └── syntax.css
├── _includes
│   ├── footer.html
│   ├── header.html
│   └── sidebar.html
├── _layouts
│   ├── default.html
│   ├── job.html
│   └── post.html
├── portfolio
│   ├── index.html
│   └── _jobs
│       └── jekyll-portfolio.markdown
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jekyll does not support this as simply as in your example yet, [it is coming in 2.0 however](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1941).

You could add a key/value pair to the YAML header of the child pages to signify that it should appear on the main portfolio index page. I have a similar setup that I use to define what pages should appear in the main navigation for my site.

The URL customisation for the portfolio pages can only be achieved by using the `permalink` setting in the YAML header of each child page.

#### portfolio/jobs/jekyll-portfolio.markdown etc

```
---
group: jobs
---
```

#### portfolio/index.html

```
<ul>
{% for node in site.pages %}
    {% if 'jobs' == node.group %}
    <li><a href="{{node.url}}">{{node.title}}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You may be able to avoid requiring the group attribute if you changed the if condition to do substring matching of the URL, but this solution is easier to understand.